# Which versions of MacOS/OSX is the voice "Victoria" available on?

Tags: macos, voice

Is there a way to find out what versions of OSX/MacOS shipped with which voices?

Comment: Can confirm it's present on Sierra and Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victoria is [present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlainTalk#Text-to-speech_in_Mac_OS_X) in every Mac OS X/OS X/macOS version. The [oldest reference](http://www.gla.ac.uk/~gwm1h/macos7.6/aboutenglishtexttospeech.html) I've found is from 1991 though and it was already available in System 7 (MacinTalk 3/MacinTalk Pro).

Comment: It's gone from macOS Ventura and onward though.

Answer (score 2):

On Ventura, my default install has "`Voice 'Victoria' not found.`" You can download Victoria under `System Settings > Accessibility > Spoken Content`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if Apple has published a list however having just now checked the installers (DVD's shipped in USA and Install App's downloaded from App Store in the USA) from Tiger to Sierra, Victoria is in all of them.